# Using dataset in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I recently code a program that everyday can add or update 20000 record in sqlite. by using `Stopwatch` i realized that all the records would add to sqlite in about 40 minutes.

by the way this is the code for adding the records :

```
string q = "INSERT INTO " + title + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(q, Assist.con_database);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@**", null);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@**", **);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@**", **);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@**", **);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@**", **);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@**", **);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@**", **);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@**", **);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@**", **);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@**", **);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@**", **);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@**", **);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@**", **);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@**", **);

                    Assist.con_database.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Assist.con_database.Close();
```

how can i reduce the time and increase the speed of adding in sqlite ?

Comment: Can you do more than one  `INSERT` in a session (open/close), maybe combine some `INSERT`s into a single query?

Answer (score 0):

You should only be adding the parameters once. Then on each insert, you just assign values to the existing parameters and call ExcecuteNonQuery.

Using a transaction will also improve performance.

So your flow should look more like:

1. Open Connection
2. Begin Transaction
3. Create command, set command text, and create parameters.
4. For each insert/update, assign values to parameters and call ExcecuteNonQuery.
5. Commit Transation
6. Close Connection